# Problems accessing store actions in pinia and vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I have a store in which I placed an action with a single method and I am trying to access that method but it did not work, I checked the documentation and everything is correct.

I know it doesn't work because the console.log() is never printed

This is my store

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useFormStore = defineStore('form', {
    state: () => {

        const fields = [ 'title', 'purpose', 'importance', 'obtain', 'provide', 'resume', 'request', 'complement', 'propose', 'agreements', 'tracing', 'lead', 'clarify', 'recognize', 'share'
        ];

        const stateObject = {};

        fields.forEach(field => {
            stateObject[field] = '';
        });

        return {
            ...stateObject,
            wasCompleted : false
        }
    },
    actions:{
        updatedStatus(){
            console.log( 'hola mundo')
            if (
                Object.values(this.$state).every(value => value !== '')
            ) {
                this.wasCompleted = true;
            }
        }
    }

})
```

And this is my component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <FormContainer>
            <template v-slot:title-section> Proceso de Interacción </template>
            <template v-slot:main-section>
                <div class="w-full my-4">
                    <label for="first_name" class="block mb-2 text-lg font-medium text-gray-900 font-semibold lg:text-2xl">Escriba el nombre del proceso:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        id="first_name" 
                        class="border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-cdg-yellow focus:border-cdg-yellow block w-full p-2.5" 
                        placeholder="Ejemplo: Importancia de la puntualidad"
                        v-model="inputTitle"
                        @input="updatedForm"
                        required
                    />
                </div>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:button-section>
                <ButtonCdg 
                    v-show="!wasCompleted"
                    @click="$emit('showSection', 'start-section')"
                >
                    <template v-slot:content>
                        Regresar
                    </template>
                </ButtonCdg>

                <ButtonCdg 
                    v-show="!wasCompleted"
                    :disabled="isDisabled"
                    :class="[ { 'opacity-50 hover:scale-100': isDisabled} ]"
                    @click="$emit('showSection', 'home-section')"
                    >
                    <template v-slot:content>
                        Siguiente
                    </template>
                </ButtonCdg>

                <ButtonCdg
                    v-show="wasCompleted"
                >
                    <template v-slot:content>
                        Ir a resultados
                    </template>
                </ButtonCdg>
            </template>
        </FormContainer>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="module">
    import FormContainer from '../FormContainer.vue';
    import ButtonCdg from '../template/ButtonCdg.vue';

    import { mapWritableState, mapActions } from 'pinia'
    import { useFormStore } from '../../stores/form'

    export default {
        components:{
            FormContainer,
            ButtonCdg
        },
        data(){
            return {
                inputTitle : '',
            }
        },
        computed : {
            ...mapWritableState( useFormStore, [ 'title', 'wasCompleted' ] ),
            isDisabled(){
                return !(this.inputTitle ?? false);
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions( useFormStore, [ 'updatedStatus' ] ),
            updatedForm(){
                this.updatedStatus()
                console.log( this.wasCompleted )
            }
            
        },
    }
</script>
```

Know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: so, is `updatedForm` ever called

Comment: [issue not reproducible](https://shorturl.at/qGL59), see the console.logs when entering input text

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, `updatedForm` is called, but the console.log inside of `updatedStatus` is never called

Comment: @yoduh what console.log can you see ?

Comment: I copied your code, so they're your console logs.  click my link which runs your code in the Pinia Playground.  open dev console in your browser.  enter text in the input.  it activates the console.logs that you say don't activate (1 from the `updatedForm` method, 1 from the `updatedStatus` action)

Comment: I removed unnecessary code that I couldn't run anyways since you didnt provide: `ButtonCdg`, `FormContainer` components, etc, but they don't seem like they would be related to the issue, but if they somehow are you should provide those in your question.  If you can reproduce using my playground link, using _minimal_ amount of code possible, please add the updated playground link to your question.

Comment: To me this code is really bad it is polluting the store